# Using sudo: Registry directory is still not writeable by the current user. Why?

Tags: php, pear, pecl

I'm trying to run:

`sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net`

Because every time I try and install a package it prompts me to run this instead. But when I run those commands I get: "Registry directory is not writeable by the current user" Now [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597944/install-oauth-pecl-error-cannot-install-php-dir-for-channel-pecl-php-net-is) is very similar but suggests using `sudo` which I'm *already* doing. When I run `sudo whoami` I'm getting `root`. Could this be related to http://pear.php.net going down?

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem (on my Mac Book), this is how I solved it:

I did a reinstall of PEAR using the following steps: http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/

After the installation of PEAR (which is bundled with PECL) my PECL commands did work again.

Comment: i followed the same steps and pear seems to be installed but i get the message: WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update and when i try i get Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Updating Channel "pecl.php.net" in registry failed"

Comment: Note: the linked article uses the http url but now it's working only by using https: `curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`. A blind copy-paste the of command will download a 
"Moved here..." html file and not the real file.